# Conversion issue with sql update statement

Tags: t-sql

I have update statement that keeps failing .

```
 Update dbo.Marker 
 set MarkId= case 
                when Ninja = 55 and cast(Tometo as varchar) = 0031A then 22 
                else MarkId 
             end
```

the data type for MarkId is int data type ,
Ninja is int data type and Tometo is varchar (9) .

this is the error i am getting

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 48
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '031A' to data type int.

Comment: Strings must be quoted `'0031A'`, `varchar` requires a size `varchar(n)` - but as you presumably want to compare to a string it must already be character data?

Comment: I have made the changes to '0031A'

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1,

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '0031A' to data type int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missing quotes around 0031A

```
Update dbo.Marker 
set MarkId= case 
              when Ninja = 55 and cast(Tometo as varchar) = '0031A' then 22 
              else MarkId 
            end
```

To find the rows that cause the issue run below query

```
select case 
         when Ninja = 55 and cast(Tometo as varchar) = '0031A' then 22 
         else MarkId 
       end
from dbo.Marker
```

then find out what rows return non-integer value. I can't help more w/o having your data.

Comment: @MJ8 that's because Flicker forgot to put length beside the varchar which made it default to 1. Try it now. You should also change this in your code unless it is literally only a single character.

Comment: @scsimon, if we don't specify length it will consider as much as needed. so there is no need to specify length.

Comment: i didn't realize the inheritance was there unlike in declarations.

Comment: @MJ8, are you still getting error? the same error? if not please tell me more detail

Comment: Why did you pick (64) instead of varchar (9) ?

Comment: @MJ8, please see my edit to see how you can find the problematic rows. you also don't need to specify length when casting.

Comment: @FLICKER technically you don't *need* to specify varchar length, [but you should](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) as if you don't specify a max length, SQL Server will do it for you, and it may not be what you expect.

Comment: This is funny , when i ran the update statement , i get error but when i go back to my table to check the change has been applied.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1 Incorrect syntax near 'A'.

Comment: What is the exact statement you run?